# Groovy ASTNode modifications does not reflect in the final class getting executed

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

Here is my usecase. I am running on version 2.1.6

I am trying to convert all array declarations to a more custom datatype which is not exposed to the end user.

For example:

`def strr = new String[4]`  will be modified to `def strr=new mycustomType(datatypeForString,4)`

`def str = [1,2,3] as String[]`  will be modified to `def str=new myCustomType(dataTypeForString,list)`

So far at the AST level, I registered a custom visitor and `visitDeclarationExpression()`.
I am currently compiling the user script using custom `GroovyClassLoader` and executing it on the fly using `myclassLoader.parseClass(usertext).newInstance().run()`

When I am executing the above the sequence(compiling, loading, executing) the AST transformations are executed(verified through `sys printls`) but the final code execution does not reflect  it.

Here is the snippet of the code that modifies the expression and sets it to the parent.

```
@Override
        public void visitDeclarationExpression(DeclarationExpression expression) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (expression.getLeftExpression() instanceof VariableExpression
                    && expression.getRightExpression() instanceof ArrayExpression) {

                   // Inspect the arrayExpressio
                expression.setRightExpression(transformArrayExpression((ArrayExpression) expression.getRightExpression()));



            }

            else if (expression.getLeftExpression() instanceof VariableExpression
                    && expression.getRightExpression() instanceof CastExpression) {
                // Inspect the cast expression
                expression.setRightExpression(transformCastExpression((CastExpression) expression.getRightExpression()));
            }

            super.visitDeclarationExpression(expression);
        }
```

Any pointers?